# best way to get my data out of gmail (google biz apps)

Tags: gmail, migration, export

I currently have 30-40 employees and were using Google Biz apps. We have been punting around the idea of going to a hosted exchange service.

for me the biggest problem is there doesn't appear to be an easy way to get some sort of dump of all the emails that are currently in each gmail account ( so of which are 10-11 gigs of data)

is there any export feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs and links at Google's [Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/). There's a section specifically about [escaping from apps for business](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/apps-for-business).

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your gmail account using an IMAP connection (you must enable this in gmail settings).  This will let you copy down all the data in almost any program that can make a IMAP connection (Just copy from the IMAP folder to a different folder).